# Is it possible to use EvtSubscribe() to subscribe to Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Trace event logs?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, event-log

I want to register a callback so my code can receive and process all new event logs for Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Trace.

To clarify, the log path for Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Trace is `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity%4Trace.etl`, and in the Windows Event Viewer, these events can be found in the tree under Application and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > WMI-Activity > Trace.

I know [`EvtSubscribe()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtsubscribe) can be used to subscribe to events on channels, but I want to know if this function can also be used for subscribing to events on Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Trace.

I know for the `ChannelPath` parameter, it says [on the function's docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtsubscribe) that

> you cannot subscribe to Analytic or Debug channels

When I view the properties for Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Trace in Event Viewer, I see the log is of type Analytic, so it seems I cannot subscribe with this function:

[image: screenshot of log properties with type highlighted]

My questions:

1. Can I use this function to subscribe to Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Trace?
2. If I cannot with this function, is there some other function in the Windows API that I can use instead that will allow me to subscribe?

Comment: Could I know if my answer is helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the article

> you `cannot subscribe` to Analytic or Debug channels

EvtSubscribe() cannot subscribe to Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Trace.

Explained in the introduction to the [Event Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa385225(v=vs.85)#event-types-and-channel-groups)

> -Direct channel
>
> **You cannot subscribe to a direct channel, but you can query a direct**
> **channel.**
>
> A direct channel is performance-oriented. Events are not processed in
> any way by the eventing system. This allows the direct channel to
> support high volumes of events.
>
> Direct channels have the following types:
>
> Analytic
>
> Analytic events are published in high volume. They describe program
> operation and indicate problems that cannot be handled by user
> intervention.

At present, in the officially provided method, seems to only be viewable through the Event Viewer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/tracing-wmi-activity#obtaining-wmi-events-through-event-viewer